# passing values between parent and child windows

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am really new to MVC 3 and need a help on this.

I have a parent window with a listbox and a child window that is a pop up. The child window has a checkbox list and i need to populate the parent window's listbox when items are selcted in the child window's checkboxlist. How to acheive this in mvc 3 razor ?

Comment: What you actually want to do, do you want to add that select checkbox value in list box or could you explain...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're actually looking for something more than just a Razor answer here, you're looking for JavaScript.

Razor is just a generator - you use it to build HTML, JavaScript (or email or XML or JSON or whatever text you want). Now, it's a really *good* generator, but it can't do the notification things you're looking to do.

JavaScript, however, will let you pass a message to the server from the popup window, and the parent window can use JavaScript to poll the server for messages.

One way to do this without writing the plumbing yourself is to use a library such as SignalR (located at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR, or you can install it in your project through NuGet) which can handle the client->server->client communication for you.

On a separate note, if the "window" is just an in-page pop-up, you don't have to do anything nearly as complicated. You can just use script on the same page to control any of the DOM elements.

Hope this helps some, cheers.